# Xamarin.iOS + RestSharp and IPv6 App Store Rejection

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, ipv6, restsharp, appstore-approval

I'm developing an iOS app using **Xamarin.iOS** and **RestSharp** to send requests to my server.
The app has been already beena approved in January but now, after some fixes, I try to update it with no success.
AppStore has sent me a message (on iTunesConnect) saying:

**Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure that it runs as expected.**

After some researches I found that IPv6 compatibility is now required.
The problem is that I don't need that and I'm not able to test on a IPv6-only network also because I'm developing and testing the application from Visual Studio on Windows using VMware build-host with Mac OSX installed on it.

How can I resolve this issue? Is there a way to test my app emulating IPv6 network on VMware making it works using RestSharp or maybe is there a way to make AppStore to approve my application?

NOTE: I've already try to change HttpClient implementation selecting *CFNetwork (iOS 6+)* as suggested on many articles on the Web but AppStore still reject my app without any advice and keeping on saying the same (useless) things.

Please help me, I'm stuck and I really don't know how to resolve this :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you see this: https://blog.xamarin.com/making-your-ios-apps-ipv6-ready/, and this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66732/does-xamarin-support-ios-ipv6-only-networks

Comment: I've followed https://blog.xamarin.com/making-your-ios-apps-ipv6-ready/ and I think I was able to map my IPv4 address string (like 79.25:56.209:1010) to an IPv6 address (it's like: ::ffff:79.25:56.209:1010). Now RestSharp doesn't recognize my IP address in the IPv6 format and it doesn't work (Unrecognized URI). How can I solve? Have I to check if the current network is IPv4 or IPv6? HO can I do that?

Comment: Creating an IPv6 IPv4-mapped address (`::ffff:0:0:0:0/96`) isn't what you want to do. Addresses in that range are not Global, or even routable, addresses. See: _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_.

Comment: Here blog.xamarin.com/making-your-ios-apps-ipv6-ready says that a possible solution is MapToIPv6() but as you say it does not work. So how I can resolve the problem?

Comment: You can't use IP address literals anymore. You must begin using domain names.

Comment: But my server has not a domain name it has a static ip address. I have to get (and pay) a new domain name like www.myserver.com?

Comment: Just a hostname under an existing domain will do fine

Comment: The problem is that the server, in this case, does not exists inside a domain. However this morning Apple has approved my application, it seems that I had to perform a clean rebuild of the project after setting the HttpClient implementation to CFNetwork (iOS 6+).

Answer (score 0):

This morning Apple has approved my application. It seems that I had to perform a clean rebuild of the project after setting the HttpClient implementation to CFNetwork (iOS 6+).

The problem is solved, for now.